# Ruby Error: undefined method `start_with?' Using Net::SSH.start

Tags: ruby

The ruby version I'm using is 1.8.6
I installed gem "net/ssh" using command "gem install net-ssh"
But on running the following script

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
  HOST = '10.102.5.100'
  USER = 'user'
  PASS = 'test'

  Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASS ) do|ssh|
    result = ssh.exec!('stat ssl')
    puts result
  end
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/config.rb:106:in `load': undefined method `start_with?' for "*":String (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `partition'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/config.rb:106:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/config.rb:106:in `partition'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/config.rb:106:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/config.rb:81:in `foreach'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/config.rb:81:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/config.rb:63:in `for'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `inject'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/config.rb:62:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/config.rb:62:in `inject'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/config.rb:62:in `for'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:239:in `configuration_for'
    from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:182:in `start'
    from TestSSH.rb:9
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: One thing is you need to upgrade Ruby...

Comment: Why are you using prehistoric `1.8.6` version? It doesn't have `String#start_with?` method.

Comment: I'm modifing some project which is using older version of ruby. But I could see in gem documentation net-ssh supports 1.8.x, can any one suggest which version of net-ssh would be compatible with ruby-1.8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments on your question point out, the problem arises because Ruby 1.8.6 doesn't have the `String#start_with?` method.  The best solution would be to upgrade to a newer Ruby.

That said, according to [the net-ssh README](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh#ruby-18-support), versions prior to 2.5.1 support Ruby 1.8.x.  A visual inspection of the file lib/net/ssh/config.rb as of net-ssh version 2.5.0 confirms that it doesn't use the `start_with?` method, so you might try that one.  Be sure to read [the changelog](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/master/CHANGES.txt) to make sure that the features you need are present in the version you use.